# FastColoredTextbox AutoWordSelection?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, user-controls

`FastColoredTextbox` is an user-control that can be downloaded in [this url](https://github.com/PavelTorgashov/FastColoredTextBox), it looks like this:

[image]

Its an amazing control but only can select one word when doubleclicking on the text, can't hold the mouse to select more words, so it only selects the entire current word over the mouse pointer even if you try to move the mouse cursor to left or right to select more text.

I have not found any information explaining the problem, and all of the official example projects has this problem.

Nobody means how to make an `AutoWordSelection` equivalent of a default `TextBox` for a `FastcoloredTextbox` control, but even the most important thing is:

How to select just more than one word with the mouse?

> UPDATE:

@**mostruash** answer is very instructive but in all this time I could not carry out the modifications by myself.

I need a huge help from a C# programmer to carry out this task, my knowledge of C# is very low and the modifications that I made to the source did not work (don't compiled), I went back to the original user-control source to not end up spoiling more. I hate to say this but this time I need the job done, this source is too much for me.

If I'm requesting for too much then maybe with the necesary extended instructions of a C# developer, explaining how to accomplish this step by step, maybe I could carry it out by myself.

> UPDATE

A video that demostrates the problem:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cs2Sh2tMvII

> UPDATE

Another demo, I show what the `FastColoredTextBox` **can't** do but I would like to do like every other text-editor can do:

[image]

Comment: I have just given it a try and I can select more than one word by holding left click and dragging the mouse.

Comment: @mostruash are you sure?, I don't mean a simple dragging, I mean to do this: 1) Double left click on a word to fully select that word. 2) hold the left button on the selected word. 3) Try to move the mouse to select another character/word. In resuming, hold a double left click and try to select more words, I can't. If you can do that then please provide details about your environment and Fastcoloredtextbox compiled version and the kind of build, and Framework, or something else that could help me to reproduce your environment to try it, thanks

Comment: I dont understand the problem.  If I dbl click a word it selects that word as expected.  If I then hold the mouse down it drags the word like most everything does (Notepad++ and even SO comments).  If I select a word, I can expand the selection using Shift+Arrows (just like everything else).  Holding the mouse down with a selection is more or less a universal Mouse Drag.  What I **can** do is select a word, then hold down shift to increase/decrease the selection by clicking a little more to the left or right (which is also how VS works at least with my config). (PowerfulSample)

Comment: @Plutonix the control can't do anything of whay you've said, I've noticed that I've misstyped the url of download in my question pointing to an image, are you sure you tried the same control that we are talking in the question?, I edited my question to share a video that demostrates the problem, it can't select more than 1 word when boudle-clicking a word (holding the mouse button of course). in any case I think that if you have not confused and you really are using FastColoredTextbox then maybe you've found a fixed/updated version? could you provide the link?

Comment: its the same control, demo one looks just like your image: https://github.com/PavelTorgashov/FastColoredTextBox I cant *double* click to add a word to the selection either, most things dont.  But Shift-Click will add words - if that does work for you here in an SO comment, it might be how your mouse is configured.

Comment: 'Shit + dbl click + hold left button' does not work for me, I don't have any "special" mouse configuration, anyways every decent text-editor can select entire words (one together other word) just doing a double-click and holding the left mouse button (included the simple Notepad.exe included in windows), its a very basic feature of every editor... this user-control doesn't help too much if it can have this feature, but is perfect in other ways.

Comment: Just to be sure we are saying the same thing: Dbl Click selects a word.  Then just move the mouse to the next word, no shifting, no click-dragging.  Shift+LClick adds the current word or part of the word to the selection. Most things - like SO comment editor, add the whole word, while the control seems to add characters up to the caret position. If that doesnt work, I would not be too hasty in discounting some mouse setting - it seems to work about the same way for mostruash   as per his comment.

Comment: @Plutonix, mostruash comment was before his answer, he made an answer 'cause he noticed the problem. in that comment he missinterpreted my words and didn't double clicked, he just single clicked.

Comment: `Dbl Click selects a word. Then just move the mouse to the next word, no shifting.` Yes but that does not works with or without shifting. thats what I'm trying to say, can't select next words.

Comment: (you left off the functional part): Shift+LeftClick modifies the current selection.  If the mouse is to the right of the selected word, Shift+LeftClick will add the characters up to the mouse pointer; it adds characters not words, but you can control that by placing the mouse at the end of the word.  If the mouse is *inside* the selection, then characters are removed from the selection.  Ctrl+Click might be nice to add a whole word, but there are not a lot of things that work that way.  See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Md-L2YCYauc

Comment: I didn't knew that but that kind of selection is abnormal, I imagine that to select all the words but one on an entire phrase you need to perform Shift+leftclick for every word (is not productive, it wastes a lot of time), I'm only interested to know how to adapt/implement a normal selection (this means hold left click to move the mouse to select other words) thanks for comment and for the video

Comment: That method is not unique/abnormal: SO uses it here in the comment editor as well, but it is for minor adjustments to the selection.  For large selections you *dont* have to select each word: put the caret at the start of a whole bunch of words; then the mouse cursor at the end of the desired selection; Shift Click selects everything in between.  I cant think of anything which supports dragging to modify words selected; its too hard to divine selecting from moving words/selections because the mouse actions are identical.  The only way I can think of is to add a contiguous word with Ctrl-Click.

Comment: Are you trying to get a NotePad-style selection thing going where you can drag-change the selection? (Note that NP also supports the Shift-Click method from the video to modify the selection).

Comment: @Plutonix I'm not sure if I understood you right, but I think yes, the selection that I've made in the GIF of my question is what I call a "normal" word selection, that's what I'm trying to do all this time, thanks for comment

Comment: Actually, I think you'll find that is only in Notepad or other *very* simple editors!  MOST things allow you to select a word and drag it to a new location (you can even do it here in SO comments).  No control/tool/app I know of supports selection drag drop AND drag-selecting like NotePad.  The mouse actions are identical so how could the code ever know which operation the user really wanted?

Comment: I don't understand what you are meaning, notepad can do a "drag-selection" (the app of the GIF is Notepad2 app), S.O. too (the web navigators), sublime text, notepad++, ms office word, openoffice, a normal .NET framework textbox and/or richtextbox, just EVERY text-editor control can select more than one word when moving the mouse, but not FastColoredTextBox.

Comment: (cant keep track of exactly how you want this to work: the video is showing a different "issue" than the GIF) FCTB supports drag selecting also, *just not when there is something already selected*. The only thing "missing" is it detecting that the drag action started at the end of a selection to modify rather than move the selection.  You can still select a lot or a little text by swiping the mouse; fine tune the selection to any point with Shift-Click. (all like Notepad++)

Comment: the video is showing the same, but remember that in the video I'm using FastColoredTextbox so I can't select more words, the video is showing the problem (can't select holding the mouse) and the GIF shows the expected result (can select holding the mouse)

Comment: I didnt understand what BLAH BLAH BLAH was trying to tell me.  The Dbl Click answer posted sounds like you want to non-contiguous selections. "Blah" 2, line 8 plus "Blah" 4 on line 5.  FCTB will let you mouse drag/swipe to add to a selection, you just cant start at the end of the selection or it thinks you want to drag the word.  Demo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cuGEFERoIzc

Comment: I might have the start of a "fix"m just not clear on what the problem is.  See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6FMkGabnfC8

Comment: @Plutonix its very good to see your progress but I need to say something: when you perform a dbl-click in the video (min 0:45) in the word "drag" and then you move the mouse to select the other word "-drop",you are not doing a normal dragdrop selection, when you do a dbl-click on "drag" and u move the mouse to "-drop" the entire word should be selected ("drag-drop") not only select the chars at your position, please just try to do the same selection in any text-editor such as Notepad or a default .NET textbox,when you do a dbl-click if u move to other word that entire word should be selected.

Comment: the wrong thing in FCTB is that when you perform a dbl-click on a word if u move the mouse u can't select anything more thatn that dbl-clicked word, now you've fixed a little that issue to be able to select more chars after doubleclicking a word, but the selection after dbl-click should be words, not chars. just see the GIF of my question to notice what I'm talking, it selects automatically the entire word "hello" when I pass the mouse hover that word, that is how work every normal texteditor, thanks for your help!

Comment: `just try to do the same selection in any text-editor such as Notepad` they all define the end of word differently. Notepad goes by spaces, so clicking code (`e.ListChangedType.ToString`), will select a lot of text; VS and smarter editors will stop at dots and the like.  FCTB just interprets a dash as a stopper.  Its not something I changed. (NotePad++ stops at dashes too)

Comment: yes but the thing of the "stoppers" doesn't matter too much, FCTB interprets him own stopper but FCTB only can select one word (so only interprets the stopper one time, when double-click on a word, denying more word-selection when moving the mouse), that's the important thing that I'm saying, FCTB can't do a normal word-selection like the GIF of my question.

Comment: `the selection after dbl-click should be words...that is how work every normal texteditor`; No, that is how THAT NP2 works, NP++ doesnt, VS doesnt (but it is using syntactical stoppers).  SelectOnlyByWord is just not in its DNA, so I give up.

Comment: no, not only notepad2, also notepad, each visualstudio textedit control (also VS IDE), navigators, just all programs after perform a dbl-click in a word and holding the left button if you move the mouse can select more words (not single chars, entire words). I didn't have installed notepad++ so I can't talk about that but we can say that notepad++ is not a "normal" program 'cause is featured, I mean customized, so that program is excluded from the "normal" word selections. sorry for my english.

Comment: Finally, I get WTF you are talking about; that most emphatically is **not** a DblClick.  Use a std TxtBox and set a break in DblClick, and do your word select thing and see when the event fires.  A dblClick is 2 mouse dns + 2 mouseUps, not 2 plus 1.  It is a Windows thing (which has changed at times) for text control type things; FCTB inherits from UserControl not TextBoxBase so it isnt in its DNA.  Having spent 4 days chasing whats wrong with Dbl-Click (nothing) I am not sure the 2+ remaining is enough to develop and test a low level replacement.

Comment: Thanks so much for your patience @Plutonix, what do you mean with "2+ remaining is enough"? anyways I don't think you spent that time in vain because you said that you've performed other improvements to the control, and that's a thing to appreciate.

Comment: It means more than half the 7 day bounty period has been spent chasing non issues; there is less than 3 days before the bounty expires to wade thru 8000 lines of someone else's code to implement a fairly low level procedure.  Those "other changes" have been reverted since they didnt have to do with the question, just my misinterpretation of it.

Comment: Is using a different control an option, something other than FastColoredTextBox?

Comment: @Mrchief no, sorry, I'm using features of that control and would be a huge problem to implement them manually in other control. thanks for comment!

Comment: Hmmm... I've used the exact same editor that Notepad++ and SharpDevelop IDE uses. You can do multi select with them.

Answer (score 19):

I've checked the source code of the project. Dragging is cancelled if a double click occurs and `SelectWord` is called.

You could modify the source code to include the feature that you request. (https://github.com/PavelTorgashov/FastColoredTextBox). In that case:

- You must trace selections that start with double clicks.
- Instead of calling `SelectWord` function, use the `Selection` class and `draggedRange` attribute to mark the selected word in `OnMouseMove`.
- You also must handle deselection of words in `OnMouseMove`.
- You must also select spaces between words in `OnMouseMove`.

The double click is handled in the code piece below:

```
            if (!isLineSelect)
            {
                var p = PointToPlace(e.Location);

                if (e.Clicks == 2)
                {
                    mouseIsDrag = false; //Here, drag is cancelled. 
                    mouseIsDragDrop = false;
                    draggedRange = null; //Drag range is nullified

                    SelectWord(p); //SelectWord is called to mark the word
                    return;
                }

                if (Selection.IsEmpty || !Selection.Contains(p) || this[p.iLine].Count <= p.iChar || ReadOnly)
                    OnMouseClickText(e);
                else
                {
                    mouseIsDragDrop = true;
                    mouseIsDrag = false;
                }
            }
```

**EDIT**:

This may require a lot of work to accomplish. So maybe you should use another tool/library. I have not studied the whole source code so there will probably be additional steps to those provided above.

For example, to trace double clicks you can do the following:

- Define a class variable/property in `FastColoredTextbox.cs`: `bool isDoubleClick`.
- Set it to `true` in `OnMouseDown` under `if(e.Clicks == 2)` condition. Set it to `false` in all other conditions.
- Set it to false in `OnMouseClick` or `OnMouseUp` or in other relevant mouse event handlers.

That way you will know if series of mouse events had started with a double click event or not. Then you would act accordingly in `OnMouseMove` because that is where you (un)mark characters or (un)mark words.

**LAST WORDS OF CAUTION**:

The author of that project did not include any inline comments or any other means of documentation so you will be studying the code line by line to understand what each function/part does.

Comment: Thankyou so much for the information but I never imagined that the proposed solution was so difficult to carry out, I'm a VB.NET programmer with few basics C# knowledges, I'm not able to do this by myself on C#. Please could indicate me how I could start trying the first step of the four steps, what really do you mean with tracing them?

Comment: Why did you unaccept? Have you figured out a better way?

Comment: no, nothing of that, I appreciate all your help but please read my question update to understand why I unmarked your answer, just I did a bounty 'cause I can't solve the problem, thanks for comment

Comment: stackoverflow.com is not freelancer.com

Comment: Sure, and I'm not asking for a job.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following statement between Line `5276` and line `5277` in the class `FastColoredTextBox.cs`:

```
SelectWord(p);
mouseIsDrag = true; // here
return;
```

Note that implementing the ultimate behavior would require a good bunch of coding. Whereas the workaround mentioned above might satisfy your needs.

Comment: Thanks, that avoids the intentional drag-cancelation but it does not select more entire words, it just selects chars as a normal drag selection, I mean this fix allows more selection of chars, not words, it disables word-selection. thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2):

As @mostruash points out in his answer, that is the place where author cancels the mouse drag. Not sure why he deliberately prevents this feature. Only he knows.

```
if (e.Clicks == 2)//Line 5270
{
    mouseIsDrag = false;
    mouseIsDragDrop = false;
    draggedRange = null;

    SelectWord(p);
    return;
}
```

I didn't read whole code, and I have no reason to do it. I just checked quickly and removed them. And it works as you expect.

```
if (e.Clicks == 2)//Line 5270
{
    //Comment or remove completely.

    //mouseIsDrag = false;
    //mouseIsDragDrop = false;
    //draggedRange = null;

    SelectWord(p);
    return;
}
```

**Note:** Am not sure this breaks something else, I've not tested. At least that works. Test it yourself.

Comment: Thanks, that avoids the intentional drag-cancelation but it does not select more entire words, it just selects chars as a normal drag selection, I mean this fix allows more selection of chars, not words, it disables word-selection. thanks for your answer

Comment: @ElektroStudios So you always want to select words when dragging? and not characters?

Comment: but always not, when you select text doing a single click it should select chars as normally, only should select words after selecting the first word in that way that shows the code that you've provided (this means doing 2 down-clicks to select the first word, then move the mouse to select more ENTIRE words), so just the same as the GIF of my question, thanks for comment!

Comment: I've tried to mess with "GoWordRight" "GoWordLeft" functions thinking that maybe they are the "key" to expand the selection of a word-dragging selection but I'm really lost with this C# sourcecode.

Comment: just I would like to be able to perform a single-click selection which select single chars and a double-click selection that select entire words, the control can't perform a normal word-drag-selection when you hold the second leftbutton-click to move next to other words because it only selects 1 word and cancels the word-selection-dragging (which you've started to fix it in the code above). do you understand me?, sorry for my english

Answer (score 1):

My solution is a bit tweaky, but seems to work at first glance.

You have to make some changes in the Code:

1. Add mouseIsWholeWordSelection flag and a Range variable which can store the initial selected range after double click (best after line 100, I guess):

   ```
   private bool mouseIsWholeWordSelection;
   private Range mouseIsWholeWordSelectionBaseRange;
   ```
2. Change the selection code for double click event as stated above and extend it a bit (line 5222):

   ```
               if (e.Clicks == 2)
               {
                   //mouseIsDrag = false;
                   mouseIsDragDrop = false;
                   mouseIsWholeWordSelection = true;
                   //draggedRange = null;

                   SelectWord(p);
                   mouseIsWholeWordSelectionBaseRange = Selection.Clone();
                   return;
               }
   ```
3. Add evaluation of dragging event for recreating selection (line 5566):

   ```
               else if (place != Selection.Start)
           {
               if (mouseIsWholeWordSelection)
               {
                   Selection.BeginUpdate();
                   var oldSelection = Selection.Clone();
                   SelectWord(place);

                   if (Selection.End >= mouseIsWholeWordSelectionBaseRange.End)
                   {
                       Selection.Start = (mouseIsWholeWordSelectionBaseRange.Start > Selection.Start) ? mouseIsWholeWordSelectionBaseRange.Start : Selection.Start;
                       Selection.End = mouseIsWholeWordSelectionBaseRange.End;
                   }
                   else if (Selection.Start < mouseIsWholeWordSelectionBaseRange.End)
                   {
                       Selection.Start = new Place(Selection.End.iChar, Selection.End.iLine);
                       Selection.End = mouseIsWholeWordSelectionBaseRange.Start;
                   }

                   Selection.EndUpdate();
                   DoCaretVisible();
                   Invalidate();
               }
               else
               {
                   Place oldEnd = Selection.End;
                   Selection.BeginUpdate();
                   if (Selection.ColumnSelectionMode)
                   {
                       Selection.Start = place;
                       Selection.ColumnSelectionMode = true;
                   }
                   else
                       Selection.Start = place;
                   Selection.End = oldEnd;
                   Selection.EndUpdate();
                   DoCaretVisible();
                   Invalidate();
               }
               return;
           }
   ```
4. Add at every place where isMouseDrag is being set to false:

   ```
   isMouseWholeWordSelection = false;
   ```

And there you go.